# python: pandas np.where vs. df.loc with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, typeerror

Np.where has been giving me a lot of errors, so I am looking for a solution with df.loc instead.

This is the np.where error I have been getting:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I am working with the following dataframe df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_A': ['AAA','AAA','ABC','CDE'],'checked': ['0','0','1','0'],'duplicate': ['True','True','False','False']})

    Column_A    checked   duplicate
0   AAA             0      True
1   AAA             0      True
2   ABC             1      False
3   CDE             0      False
```

I want to create an additional flag, if checked is 0 and duplicate is True.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
df['flag'] = (np.where((df['checked'] == 'Y') &(df['duplicate'] == 'True'), 'Y', '0'))

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

I tried it with df.loc:

```
df['flag'] = (df.loc[df['checked'] == 'Y']& df.loc[df['duplicate'] == 'True'], 'Y','0')

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

and I get the same error!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your `boolean` are not `string`s, so need remove `'`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_A': ['AAA','AAA','ABC','CDE'],
                  'checked': ['0','0','1','0'],
                  'duplicate': [True, True, False, False]})

df['flag'] = np.where((df['checked'] == 'Y') &(df['duplicate'] == True), 'Y', '0')
print (df)
  Column_A checked  duplicate flag
0      AAA       0       True    0
1      AAA       0       True    0
2      ABC       1      False    0
3      CDE       0      False    0
```

Or if compare with `boolean` column, `== True` can be omited:

```
df['flag'] = np.where((df['checked'] == 'Y') &(df['duplicate']), 'Y', '0')
print (df)
  Column_A checked  duplicate flag
0      AAA       0       True    0
1      AAA       0       True    0
2      ABC       1      False    0
3      CDE       0      False    0
```

Also if need check `checked` need `'` because `strings`:

```
df['flag'] = np.where((df['checked'] == '0') &(df['duplicate'] == True), 'Y', '0')
print (df)
  Column_A checked  duplicate flag
0      AAA       0       True    Y
1      AAA       0       True    Y
2      ABC       1      False    0
3      CDE       0      False    0
```

EDIT:

Solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df['flag'] = '0'
mask = (df['checked'] == '0') &(df['duplicate'])
df.loc[mask, 'flag'] = 'Y'
print (df)
  Column_A checked  duplicate flag
0      AAA       0       True    Y
1      AAA       0       True    Y
2      ABC       1      False    0
3      CDE       0      False    0
```

Comment: oh - I see! how woul dI do an OR statement instead of &?

Comment: thank you very much - is there a way to do it with df.loc?

Comment: I think yes, it depends what you need. `&` is bitwise `and` and `|` is bitwise `or`.