# How to use conditional statements on the existing columns to create a new pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'true': [1, 2, 3], 'billed': [4, 5, 6], 'genre':['a','b','c']})

    true    billed  genre
0    1         4    a
1    2         5    b
2    3         6    c
```

I want to create a new column `selection` based on `true` but with condition on `genre` and achieve something like this:

```
[Expected]
    true    billed  genre   selection
0     1        4      a       1
1     2        5      b       2
2     3        6      c       6

[Attempt]
df['selection']=(df['true'] if df['genre'] is 'a' or 'b' else df['billed'])

    true    billed  genre   selection
0     1        4      a       1
1     2        5      b       2
2     3        6      c       3
```

I do not want to loop through the dataframe.

Comment: [numpy where](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) solves this for you; i'm pretty sure there are examples of conditionals on SO. here's one : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44569952/7175713)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: pandas np.where vs. df.loc with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569879/python-pandas-np-where-vs-df-loc-with-multiple-conditions). Specifically, `df['selection'] = np.where(df['genre'].isin(['a', 'b']), df['true'], df['billed'])`.

Comment: `df['selection'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['true'] if row['genre'] in ('a', 'b') else row['billed'], axis=1)`